# Problem with | (\vert) in LaTeX

Tags: tex-core

I am using a stylesheet to convert MathML to LaTeX. When I try to convert:

```
<mrow>
    <mo>|</mo>
    <mi>a</mi>
    <mo>|</mo>
</mrow>
```

In latex that should be written as:

```
\left\vert a \right\vert
```

Now the problem. I could easily write:

```
\vert a \vert
```

But in case when instead of 'a' there is some large expression, the vertical lines will not be tall as the expression, but stay the small. That is what `\left` and `\right` are for. Is there any easy way to do this that I don't see here, or do I need to parse the MathML in a way so I would know which vertical line is left and which is right? Thanks.

Comment: It's wrong to say that the text *should* be written `\left\vert a\right\vert`. The correct way (with `amsmath`) is `\lvert a\rvert`; `\left` and `\right` *may* be added (but in many cases `\bigl` or `\bigr` would suffice, or other similar pairs). The MathML input is wrong to begin with, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. When I try to write just `\lvert` {some equation} `\rvert`, vertical bars are not scaled. `\bigl` and `\bigr` does not help either. I need to write `\left` and `\right`. As for mathML input, yes, some examples are wrong, there is nothing I can do about that.

Comment: your question is about the conversion software you are using not about, so it isn't clearly on topic here, but as you have not said what convertor you are using then it is impossible to answer.  but it is true that `|a|` is better latex for the absolute value than `\left\vert \a\right\vert`

Answer (score 1):

OK, I solved it by writing a template:

```
<xsl:template match="m:mrow">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count(./*)=3 and ./*[1]/m:mo = '|' and ./*[3]/m:mo = '|'">
            <xsl:text>\left\vert</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./*[2]"/>
            <xsl:text>\right\vert</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

It may not be the perfect, but it works for the cases I need it to work for.